# Serializable on abstract base classes intended for JSF/CDI beans

Tags: java, jsf, serialization, jsf-2, cdi

I have created a few base classes to generalize functionality. These classes are inherited by concrete CDI beans like:

```
@Named
@WhateverCdiScoped
public class PseudoEntityManager extends AbstractManager<PseudoEntity> implements Serializable
{
    ...
}
```

**Q's**:

Is it a good practice to put the `Serializable` interface onto the abstract base class, here `AbstractManager<T>`, so that implementers don't have to put the `implements Serializable` onto each concrete sub class (as shown above)?

What are the pros and cons for the "base class policy" and "concrete sub class policy"?

Are there any other consequences overlooked, e.g. about the location of `private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;`?

Comment: I've done this with my POJOs. As a POJO is something that I'm going to serialize it makes sense to have an abstract superclass which implements `Serializable`. Don't know for sure if it's the case of your beans.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, each class should have its own serialVersionUID (because it's private, it only belongs to that class).

The rest of the question is really a coding standard question.  My personal opinion is that serializable, as well as most other marker interfaces are just like any other interface.  they handle polymorphism fine and you shouldn't need to redeclare the use of the interface.  Understand that all you're doing is making them serializable.  you're not enforcing any CDI scopes by doing this.